# Random unique number arrays comparison C++

Tags: c++, arrays, random, 2d

I have two 2D arrays of type integer. I assign random values into both theses arrays. The values in the first column represent the x value for a and b, and the values in the second column represent the y value for a and b.

Declaring the arrays

```
int ROW(12), COLUMN(2);
int a[ROW][COLUMN];
int b[ROW][COLUMN];
```

Assigning random values to the arrays

```
    for (int i(0); i < ROW; i++)
    {
        a[i][0] = Random(SIZEX - 2);    //horizontal coordinate in range [1..(SIZEX - 2)]
        a[i][1] = Random(SIZEY - 2);    //vertical coordinate in range [1..(SIZEY - 2)]
    }

    for (int i(0); i < (ROW - 4); i++)
    {
        b[i][0] = Random(SIZEX - 2);    //horizontal coordinate in range [1..(SIZEX - 2)]
        b[i][1] = Random(SIZEY - 2);    //vertical coordinate in range [1..(SIZEY - 2)]
    }
```

I need to find a way in which I can compare the x and y value of an row, with the x and y value of each other row in each array aswell as with the other array and make sure each combination of x and y is unique for both of the arrays.

As the coordinates will relate to the position in another array.

I have a very messy solution which will work for one of the arrays.

```
for (int i(0); i < COLUMN; ++i)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        while (b[i][0] == spot.x)
            b[i][0] = Random(SIZEX - 2);
    }

    if (i == 1)
    {
        while ((b[i][0] == spot.x) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 1][0]))
            b[i][0] = Random(SIZEX - 2);
    }

    if (i == 2)
    {
        while ((b[i][0] == spot.x) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 2][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 1][0]))
            b[i][0] = Random(SIZEX - 2);
    }

    if (i == 3)
    {
        while ((b[i][0] == spot.x) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 3][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 2][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 1][0]))
            b[i][0] = Random(SIZEX - 2);
    }

    if (i == 4)
    {
        while ((b[i][0] == spot.x) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 4][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 3][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 2][0])
            || (b[i][0] == b[i - 1][0]))
            b[i][0] = Random(SIZEX - 2);
    }

    if (i == 5)
    {
        while ((b[i][0] == spot.x) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 5][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 4][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 3][0])
            || (b[i][0] == b[i - 2][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 1][0]))
            b[i][0] = Random(SIZEX - 2);
    }

    if (i == 6)
    {
        while ((b[i][0] == spot.x) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 6][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 5][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 4][0])
            || (b[i][0] == b[i - 3][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 2][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 1][0]))
            b[i][0] = Random(SIZEX - 2);
    }

    if (i == 7)
    {
        while ((b[i][0] == spot.x) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 7][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 6][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 5][0])
            || (b[i][0] == b[i - 4][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 3][0]) || (b[i][0] == b[i - 2][0]) 
            || (b[i][0] == b[i - 1][0]))
            b[i][0] = Random(SIZEX - 2);
    }
}
```

But it only compares the x (first column). spot represents a struct variable.

Comment: Can you show us what you've attempted so far? There's nothing built in that will do this for you.

Comment: Don't you want just to shuffle the arrays?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try

```
for (int i=0;i<12;i++)
{for (int k=i+1;k<12;k++)
 {if (a[i][0]==a[k][0])
 cout<<"a["<<i<<"][0] same as a["<<k<<"][0]"<<endl;//you can assign a new number to a[k][0]
}};
```